# If $\sum f_j^2 $ and $\sum g_j^2$ conrverge uniformly, show that $\sum f_j g_j$ converges absolutely and uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

> Let $(f_j)$ and $(g_j)$ be sequences of real functions defined on [a,b]. Assume that both $\Sigma_j f_j^2$ and $\Sigma_j g_j^2$ converge uniformly on $[a,b]$. Show that $\Sigma_j f_j g_j$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $[a,b]$.

My attempt to prove converge absolutely:

We have $(\sum_{j=1}^nf_j g_j)^2\le (\sum_{j=1}^nf_j^2)(\sum_{j=1}^ng_j^2)$

now let $f_j = |f_j| $ and $g_j = |g_j| $, then the above inequality becomes $(\sum_{j=1}^n|f_j g_j|)^2\le (\sum_{j=1}^n|f_j|^2)(\sum_{j=1}^n|g_j|^2)$.

Notice that the RHS, $(\sum_{j=1}^n|f_j|^2)(\sum_{j=1}^n|g_j|^2) =  (\sum_{j=1}^nf_j^2)(\sum_{j=1}^ng_j^2)$

Thus, I have $(\sum_{j=1}^n|f_j g_j|)^2\le (\sum_{j=1}^nf_j^2)(\sum_{j=1}^ng_j^2)$.

Because the question said both $\Sigma_j f_j^2$ and $\Sigma_j g_j^2$ converge uniformly on [a,b], that means both series converges on [a,b]. Then I know $(\sum_{j=1}^n|f_j g_j|)^2$ converges?

Comment: Do you know comparison test? Do you see how that answers your question?

Comment: Yes, I know comparison test. But it's weird for me to say the square of a series converges.

Comment: Well you can take square roots and you are done

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Do I have a theorem that allow me to do square roots?

Comment: @Mariana: yes, $|x|\le |y|\iff x^2\le y^2$ for all real $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I don't know how to show it is uniform convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
By Cauchy Schwarz inequality, we have 
$(\sum_{i=1}^nf_i g_i)^2\le (\sum_{i=1}^nf_i^2)(\sum_{i=1}^ng_i^2)$. Can you finish?

Comment: I am not sure how to show it converges absolutely. When a series converges uniformly, can I say it just converges?

Comment: @Mariana: for absolute convergence, you’ll have to apply CS inequality slightly differently. Apply CS on  $(\sum |f_ig_i|)^2$ as above and you have your answer.

Comment: You should try to refrain from answering PSQs and instead engage with asker to improve their question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I added my attempt. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @Mariana: you don't need to justify yourself, this is an American site and we have freedom to engage with whoever we want. Maybe in other countries they love censorship.

Comment: I can only show it is converges based on your direction. I don't know how to show it is uniform convergence.

Comment: @Mariana: You may use Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence and finish using what I stated in my answer/hint above :).

Comment: @Koro Say a big n, and from n to m, the sum of $f_i g_i$, then?

Comment: @Mariana: you'll have a big $N$ such that for all $m\ge n\ge N, \sum_{i=m}^n f_i^2$ and $\sum_{i=m}^n g_i^2$ both are less than $ \epsilon$ and so apply CS inequality from $i=m$ to $i=n$ (and not from $i=1$ to $i=n$). Do you see it now?

Comment: @Koro But when I apply CS inequality, the CS inequality is from i = 1 to n, not m to n.

Comment: @Mariana: You can actually apply CS from m to n also.  :)